# Javascript change mouse up down to left right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to design a horizontal site, so when I scroll up and down I want the page to go from left to right. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use the browser's scroll bar to do this, or you want to change behavior for the mouse wheel scroll?

for the first case you'd have to fake some of the interface stuff. have a div that takes up the whole window, and make that div as tall as your actual content is wide (approximately, you'll have to tune it). and then your actual conent can be fixed in place, just leaving the lower div's scroll bar visible. then you can watch for a scroll event and adjust your content view accordingly.

the second case isn't too bad- you need to determine what mouse wheel action happened and then do a manual operation to +/- the scrollLef operation for the window. i've seen this done and i hated the site but it was an interesting idea. mouse events aren't very uniform across browsers but i'll assume someone will pop in to tell you how awesome a particular jquery plugin is for that.

Answer (score 1):

This'll be a horrible user experience, but you could do it by monitoring the scoll events in javascript, and adjusting the horizontal scroll appropriately.

Comment: why do you say that? 'Horrible user experience', do you not like horizontal sites in general?

Comment: Maybe Scrollable is usable here http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Comment: @midday that changes the box leaving the other box behind. I want to harness the browser scroll not invent another.

Comment: it's horrible because you'll be moving the mouse up/down but the screen will move left/right.  same with scroll wheels. Yuck.

Comment: It's experimental, for sure, and I certainly wouldn't put it on anything that's going to get a lot of traffic, but playing around with strange behaviors like this is what makes web design fun and innovative.

Comment: It's a question of user expectations; if I scroll down, does that mean left, or right? If it's a proof-of-concept, or a game of some sort maybe, then perhaps it'd be ok, but overall it'd just be annoying to your users.

Comment: The Windows 8 tile screen scrolls left/right using the mouse wheel. It doesn't take long to get use to it.